# Clearing WebBrowser Control Passwords in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a baby browser on my C#.Net Application that navigates normally as a normal browser and go back and forward, Stop, Refresh...

But there is one thing I can't manage to accomplish it, clearing Password Cache..

How can I possibly do this using C#.Net code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to Clear the Cache in Visual C# .NET in the following article :

[Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201)

**Edit :**
Alternative in case previous didn't work :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clearIECache();
}

void clearIECache()
{
    ClearFolder(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath
       (Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)));
}

void ClearFolder(DirectoryInfo folder)
{

        foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // files used by another process exception
            {

            }
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subfolder in folder.GetDirectories())
        {
            ClearFolder(subfolder); 
        }

}
```

Comment: Just convert the console application in the link to a class replacing the void main with normal method name. Added some hints in the answer.

Comment: change it to public and not private

Comment: This is crazy , i just tested it and it stuck in an infinite loop when clearing the cache! Edited the answer.

Comment: The code is working but I get an exception (Access Denied), I tried running it as Administrator, but still the error message appears.. :S